# CakePHP: Managing table names in a controller with a single variable

Tags: php, cakephp

In controller A, I load a model not associated with this controller. I'm interested in managing the model name of controller B with a single variable, so I don't have to manually change many lines if the table/model B's name changes.

For example below is the controller A's code:

```
public $modelBName = 'ModelB';

public function controller_a_function() {
    $this->loadModel($this->modelBName);    // I use the variable here for model B

    $this->ModelB->model_b_function();    // COMMENT #1
}
```

Question:
For the line commented "COMMENT #1," how do I use the variable name instead of explicitly written out word 'ModelB'? This line appears multiple times throughout the code, and I would like to use the variable `$modelBName` if possible. `ModelB` will likely not change, but if it does for some reason, it would be nice to just change one variable instead of editting multiple lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer; use this:

```
$this->{$this->modelBName}->find('all');
```

Note the curly brackets {} around the property name. more information can be found in the manual;

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

A cleaner approach may be a sort of 'factory' method;

```
/**
 * Load and return a model
 *
 * @var string $modelName
 *
 * @return Model
 * @throws MissingModelException if the model class cannot be found.
 */
protected function model($modelName)
{
    if (!isset($this->{$modelName})) {
        $this->loadModel($modelName);
    }

    return $this->{$modelName};
}
```

Which can be used like this;

```
$result = $this->model($this->modelBName)->find('all');
debug($result);
```

And, if you don't want to specify the model, but want it to return a '$this->modelBName' automatically;

```
/**
 * Load and return the model as specified in the 'modelBName' property
 *
 * @return Model
 * @throws MissingModelException if the model class cannot be found.
 */
protected function modelB()
{
    if (!isset($this->{$this->modelBName})) {
        $this->loadModel($this->modelBName);
    }

    return $this->{$this->modelBName};
}
```

Which can be used like this:

```
$result = $this->modelB()->find('all');
debug($result);
```

Comment: Hey, the curly brackets work. I wondering, though, if this is a good and common practice? I have not seen anyone else's code that does this. They always just do `$this->ModelName->someFunction` wherever they need to use a model. Any idea?

Comment: If you use the regular '$uses' array, the model will already be loaded and you don't have to manually load the model. I don't really see an advantage in using a variable for the modelname. IMO it will even make it less 'obvious' which model you're currently working on. E.g. Calling $this->User->save() is a lot clearer than $this->{$this->modelName}->save();

Comment: I'm currently just using `loadModel('model_name')` in the controller actions if they need it instead of using the `$uses` array because not every action needs the entire set of models being used in the controller. I think I will go with readability on this one and take  your suggestion.

Comment: Also, If models already have a relation between them, you don't have to load them separately. E.g. If User->hasmany->Posts, you only have to add 'User' to the $uses array, and call $this->User->Post->something() if needed. However, if you only need a model for a single action, it's also possible to initiate a model like this: ClassRegistry::init('SomeModel')->someMethod(); this way the Model won't be 'attached' to the Contoller, just initialised.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused between model name and table name. You can set a model to use a different database table by using the `$useTable` property, for example:

```
class User extends AppModel {

    public $useTable = 'users_table'; // Database table used

}

class Product extends AppModel {

    public function foo() {
         $this->loadModel('User');

         $this->User->find('all');
    }
}
```

You should never need to change the name of the model, and if the name of the database table changes you can simply update the `$useTable` property in the model.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. I see that I did get the terms confused, but I have fixed my post. I'm basically looking to use a variable for the model B's name, `ModelB`, instead of writing it out in the COMMENT #1 line.